# get product id set in const use onPress in react native loop

Tags: react-native, onpress

I want to add key={item.id} value in pid use onPress, and her data come to data base use loop in react native

```
const addToWishlist = () => {
     const [pid, setPid] = useState('');
}
return (
  <>
   {ProductData.map((item, index) => {
     return (
       <View key={index} style={styles.prod}>
         <TouchableOpacity onPress={addToWishlist} key={item.id}>
           <Feather name="heart" color={heartColor} style={{fontSize:16}}/>
         </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
     )
   })}
  </>
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function should accept an arg `id` and you must send it when the `onPress` is triggered.

`onPress={() => addToWishlist(item.id)}`

```
const addToWishlist = (id) => {
  console.log(id)
  // const [pid, setPid] = useState('');
  // You should not declare a hook in a function
}

return (
  <>
   {ProductData.map((item, index) => (
     <View key={index} style={styles.prod}>
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => addToWishlist(item.id)} key={item.id}>
         <Feather name="heart" color={heartColor} style={{fontSize:16}}/>
       </TouchableOpacity>
     </View>
   )})
 </>
)
```